# How to retrieve value from the resultset in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, jsp-tags

I have a scenario like this:

```
<sql:query var="var1">
    SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLA='AA' AND COLB='BB'
</sql:query>
```

I know it for sure that it will return only one row, and i want to display the retrieved values i.e. COLA , COLB and COLC in a jsp. I am trying with

```
<c:out value="${var1.COLA}" />
<c:out value="${var1.COLB}" />
<c:out value="${var1.COLC}" />
```

Since the query will return only one row i have not placed above code in`<forEach>`  . but it is not printing those values instead I get error like

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: 
The class `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl` does not have the property 'COLA'
```

Kindly let me know how to print those values in a jsp?

Comment: Read the javadoc for `ResultImpl` - http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/apidocs/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/sql/ResultImpl.html. `getRowsByIndex()` might be a start.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified the datasource

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db" user="root" password=""/>
<sql:query dataSoucrce="${snapshot}" var="var1">
  select * from db.t1;
</sql:query>
```